# Finding average based on criteria in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet containing rating data for hundreds of leaders in our organization. Using VBA, I would like to find the average rating on each question for each leader. Example:

My data is is the following format

```
-Name      Question      Rating
-John      Q1            4 
-John      Q1            2
-John      Q2            3
-John      Q2            2
-Heather   Q1            5
-Heather   Q1            3
-Heather   Q2            3
-Heather   Q2            1
```

I would like to get the below result based on this data.

```
John
 Q1 Average 3
 Q2 Average 2.5
Heather
 Q1 Average 4
 Q2 Average 2
```

Hopefully this is clear. I am somewhat new to VBA, so thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using pivot table?

Comment: There is a function called AVERAGEIFS that seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I second Lisa's suggestion of a PivotTable.  There's no need for custom VBA code when Excel has out-of-the-box functionality to do what you want.

[image: PivotTable example]